# How can I stop my description text from going beyond the margin

Tags: tables, lists, enumitem, description

The text is going over my page. How can i fix that?

[image]

```
\documentclass[DIV=15, paper=a4, paper=portrait, pagesize=auto]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[11pt]{moresize}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\newcommand{\indentitem}{\setlength\itemindent{25pt}}
\newcommand*{\sectioncolor}{blue}
\newcommand*{\sectionformat}{\centering\color{\sectioncolor}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FFC296}
\begin{document}
\SetLabelAlign{rightbox}{\hspace{-19ex}\rlap{#1\quad}}
\setlist[description,1]{align=rightbox,labelsep=0pt,rightmargin=0pt}
% \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}


            \section{Student 55d5396fed}
            \begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{19ex}}p{2em}}
            \begin{description}

                \item[Project Number] 55d5396fed

                \item[Project Name] We have already seen that a case of
                semigrammaticalness of a different sort is necessary to impose
an interpretation on irrelevant intervening contexts in selectional rules.

                \item[Proponent] Of course, the fundamental error of regarding functional notions as categorial is to be regarded as
nondistinctness in the sense of distinctive feature theory.

            \end{description}
            \end{tabular}



                       \hangindent2em
                        \hangafter=0


\end{document}
```

[My code on writelatex.com](https://www.writelatex.com/170108dpmjdt)

Comment: Make the `p` column less wide.

Comment: @adrianN Did you mean "wider"? user17, there is no reason to nest a `description` environment inside a `tabular` environment, especially with such a narrow column (`2em` is very very very narrow). Get rid of the `tabular` environment.

Comment: @adrianN   My original code was not like that , i had the full page wide columns

Comment: Apparently the website you linked to saves my edits... I changed it from 42 or something like that to 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is seldom a case for nesting a `description` environment inside a `tabular` environment like you did, especially with such a narrow column; `2em` is very very very narrow (an "em" is a font-dependent length corresponding to the width of an "M" of the font used). Get rid of the `tabular` environment.

Moreover, your modification of the `description` environment using `\setlist` from `enumitem` is not very wise: it makes it stick out of the page on the left. I suggest getting rid of that line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[DIV=15, paper=a4, paper=portrait, pagesize=auto]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[11pt]{moresize}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\newcommand{\indentitem}{\setlength\itemindent{25pt}}
\newcommand*{\sectioncolor}{blue}
\newcommand*{\sectionformat}{\centering\color{\sectioncolor}}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FFC296}
\begin{document}
\SetLabelAlign{rightbox}{\hspace{-19ex}\rlap{#1\quad}}
%\setlist[description,1]{align=rightbox,labelsep=0pt,rightmargin=0pt} <---- unwise
% \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{white}

\section{Student 55d5396fed}
\begin{description}            
    \item[Project Number] 55d5396fed                
    \item[Project Name] We have already seen that a case of semigrammaticalness
        of a different sort is necessary to impose an interpretation on irrelevant
        intervening contexts in selectional rules.
    \item[Proponent] Of course, the fundamental error of regarding functional
        notions as categorial is to be regarded as nondistinctness in the sense of
        distinctive feature theory.
\end{description} 



\end{document}
```